# Flatten and Parsing Json using Azure Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have table which has the following data

```
Code Info
AE   [{"key":"eng","value":"ABC"},{"key":"fra","value":"DEF"}]
US   [{"key":"eng","value":"XYZ"},{"language":"dut","value":"123"}]
UK   [{"key":"arb","value":"KLM"}]
```

I want to transform it using Azure Data Flow as below

```
Code InfoKey  InfoValue
AE    eng       ABC
AE    fra       DEF
US    eng       XYZ
US    dut       123
UK    arb       KLM
```

I had tried using flatten transformation, parsing transformation and nothing was succeeded. when I use flatten transformation on Column 'Info', it gives the same output. and when i tried parsing json, its not able to transform the data at all.

Could someone help how we can transform this data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced the scenario and was able to parse data to multiple columns.

**Step1**:

•   Add the output of the source to derived column transformation and split the JSON value row (Info) into multiple arrays.

•   Here I am replacing few values before applying split to get the correct array representation.

```
split(replace(replace(replace(Info, '[', ''),']',''),'},','}},'),'},')
```

[image]

•   Preview of the derived column: Info for code **AE** is split into array *Info[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAPKr.png)* & *Info[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsghp.png)*.

[image]

**Step2**:

•   Connect the output of the derived column to `Flatten` transformation to flatten the arrays to multiple rows.

•   Select *Info[]* under **Unroll by** and **Unroll root** to flatten Info array to multiple rows.

[image]

•   Output of flatten transformation

[image]

**Step3**:

•   Connect the `flatten` output to `parse` transformation to parse the array values to multiple columns.

•   Select the column to **parse** in the expression and parsed column names with type in Output column type.

[image]

•   *Output of parse transformation*: Data is parsed into 2 columns Key and value.

[image]

•   Here there is a *NULL* value for Code *US* and value *123*, this is because the source does not have a **key** column for code US in the 2nd array.

[image]

**Step4**:

*Sink Output*:

[image]