# Azure Data Flow Flatten and Parsing key/value column

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to transform a key/value data into column using Azure Data Flow. Basically this:

`{"key":"rate1","value":"123"}-{"key":"rate2","value":"456"}`

into this:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| rate1 | 123 |
| rate2 | 456 |

I was following this example here ( [Flatten and Parsing Json using Azure Data Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69109110/flatten-and-parsing-json-using-azure-data-flow) ), and everything was look good until I tried to use parse.

The output just shows the value column, not the key. I don't know why. Below are my dataflow settings.

Source query: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q8Xb.png

Source Data preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNj8x.png

Derived Column: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0g1N.png

Derived Column Data preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtVY7.png

Flatten: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkp7P.png

Flatten Data preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM6h1.png

Parse: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUJpr.png

Parse Data preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC42Y.png

Anyone have any idea what I'm missing?

Edit: My source is Snowflake

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced the above and got same result after **parse transformation**.

[image]

The above process is correct, may be the preview is not showing correctly. You can view the **desired result as individual columns by using derived column transformation after parse**.

[image]

In sink select the desired columns by **Mapping**->deselect **auto mapping**->**+**->Fixed mapping.

[image]

**Sink Data preview:**.

[image]

Comment: Instead adding a derivedColumn2, I added a select and selected key/value and now the data preview is working correctly. Anyway, thanks for the answer it helped a lot :)